# Handling aspx page errors

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I handle exceptions in the case where the code is in the ASPX page and not in the code behind.

For example, I'm binding a gridview to a sqldatasource and there is no connection to the database. How do I catch this exception?

I tried adding Page_Error method to the page but it is not reached.

Thank you.

Comment: There are many ways to handle exceptions, see [Error Handling](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/aspnet-error-handling)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Global.asax Application_Error, you can find a ref here:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx

There are many ways, this is just a global one.